# date pipe does not work for elements with FormControlName property set

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, date-pipe

Using reactive-forms sample application
I have added curr_date form control which has a pipe to format the date in desired format.
In ts file, form group has the curr_date property which has preset value in different format.

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <label for="first-name">First Name: </label>
  <input id="first-name" type="text" formControlName="firstName" required>

  <label for="last-name">Last Name: </label>
  <input id="last-name" type="text" formControlName="lastName">

  <label for="zip">Date: </label>
**  <input id="curr_date" type="text" formControlName="curr_date" [value]="profileForm.value.curr_date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'">**

  <div formGroupName="address">
    <h2>Address</h2>

    <label for="street">Street: </label>
    <input id="street" type="text" formControlName="street">

    <label for="city">City: </label>
    <input id="city" type="text" formControlName="city">

    <label for="state">State: </label>
    <input id="state" type="text" formControlName="state">

    <label for="zip">Zip Code: </label>
    <input id="zip" type="text" formControlName="zip">
  </div>

  <div formArrayName="aliases">
    <h2>Aliases</h2>
    <button type="button" (click)="addAlias()">+ Add another alias</button>

    <div *ngFor="let alias of aliases.controls; let i=index">
      <!-- The repeated alias template -->
      <label for="alias-{{ i }}">Alias:</label>
      <input id="alias-{{ i }}" type="text" [formControlName]="i">
    </div>
  </div>


  <p>Complete the form to enable button.</p>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>

<hr>

<p>Form Value: {{ profileForm.value | json }}</p>

<p>Form Status: {{ profileForm.status }}</p>

<button type="button" (click)="updateProfile()">Update Profile</button>
```

In ts file, I have added curr_date formcontrol as follows:

```
export class ProfileEditorComponent {
  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: [''],
    curr_date: ['2008-03-28T00:00:00', Validators.required],
    address: this.fb.group({
      street: [''],
      city: [''],
      state: [''],
      zip: [''],
    }),
    aliases: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.control('')
    ])
  });
```

Here is what I noticed,

[The element has FormControlName attribute and the date is not formatted as per date pipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSPMT.png)

[FormControlName attribute is removed from element and the date is now formatted as per date pipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OdLZ.png)

Any help to resolve this issue is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be super easy

```html
<input id="curr_date" type="text" ...
```

change that to

```html
<input id="curr_date" type="date" ...
```

You shouldn't have to deal with any type of conversion or anything else.

Also, only use `formControlName` or `value` but never both. If you have a reactive form built, then set the value in the TS and not in the HTML.

Comment: Hi @Myles, thanks for your response. I see that now it shows input date control along with datepicker with "mm/dd/yyyy" text written in it. I am assuming it picks up this specific date format from computer locale. But I wonder why it does not show the preset date assigned to curr_date in ts. I confirmed it displays preset  values for first and last name form fields.
**HTML** 
<input id="curr_date" type="date" formControlName="curr_date">
**TS**
....
    firstName: ['Ajit', Validators.required],
    lastName: ['Test'],
    curr_date: ['2008-03-28T00:00:00'],
...
...

Regards, Ajit

Comment: Just noticed that if you preset the date in ts using yyyy-mm-dd format, it is displayed in date input field presumably because it's a date field and not datetime field.

Comment: Yep exactly, if you use datetime it uses a completely different picker modal and everything. Glad to be of help!